# Get width after data binding in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In directive, I write an element with ngRepeat, and I need to get width after data binding.

I try to use post in link, but it also can't work.

How can I get the width in directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width isn't available in `link` as the element isn't part of the DOM yet. You can however watch for any change of the width and handle the change once it occurs.

```
scope.watch(function() {return element.style.width}, function() {
  // handle width change here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile: function () {
    return {
        pre: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            function getWidth() {
                return iElement.width();
            }
        }

        $scope.$watch(getWidth, function (newWidth) {

            ...
        });
    }
}
```